# How do I invoke or start an application from command line?

Tags: 14.04

I just did `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-pomodoro` on my Ubuntu. I'm wondering how I invoke or start the application.

Answer (score 1):

Press ALT+F2 and write the name of your application , then click on it :)

Comment: I couldn't find it when I  used that.  If I did sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-pomodoro   to install, what would be name of the application that I have to search for?

Comment: type: pomodoro  and then search for it in the opened window

Comment: It just shows a png image, no applications are found.  http://gnomepomodoro.org/  Thanks a lot for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `gnome-pomodoro` to run it.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, run this

```
dpkg -l gnome-shell-pomodoro
```

that will list out all of the installed files.  If there is an executable to run from the command line, usually it will be in a bin directory. Some of these shell applets cannot be run from the command line, they must be invoked by another program. I don't run this program you mention, so I cannot say for sure.

It looks to me like you are in luck. The file list here (https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/gnome-shell-pomodoro/filelist) says you run, well, the obvious one :)

```
/usr/bin/gnome-pomodoro
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Pomodoro.desktop
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Pomodoro.service
/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell-pomodoro/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell-pomodoro/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell-pomodoro/copyright
```

Comment: I went to /usr/bin from command line and then did  ./gnome-pomodoro . It only open the preferences window and doesn't actually run the app

Comment: You don' t need to cd to /usr/bin. Almost for sure, /usr/bin is  in your PATH variable, and if you  open a terminal and run "gnome-pomodoro" it will run.  You say that opens the preferences app, which means you are in the situation I warned you about. Perhaps this is not a "program" you can run separately, it is an applet that has to run by some other program. Possible you run "gnome-pomodoro --help" to see if it has options. More generally, get used to the  command line. Try some things like "firefox &" or "emacs &" or other apps that I know will work, supposing you have those installed.

Comment: I notice in "man gnome-pomodoro" there are command line options. Appears you are describing the behavior with the "--preferences" flag. I wonder what happens if you run with the argument "--no-default-window". That is described as "Run as a background service". Maybe that is what you are trying to achieve. Sorry I can't help more, but I don't want to install 50 packages just to try that one app.